# How can I Change Base64 fill in react?

Tags: reactjs, svg, base64

I have  my product image coming from a DB and i want to manipulate it.
The image is an svg file and since it pulls as an svg file and not as raw data I converted it into Base64 so that when I use devtools I can see the fills. ( when i store the svg as an svg fill it is not possible to see the fill )
Then the return in my react app is an iframe (which is not the best idea but an image tag  will not let me see the data )\

```
return (
    <div>
              <div>
                <iframe
                  className="art"
                  width="200px"
                  height="300px"
                  frameBorder="0"
                  src={product.image}
                ></iframe>
              </div>
</div>
```

the Prodcut image is

```
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 53.87 259.85">
  <g id="three" data-name="&lt;three&gt;" className="three">
    <rect x="0.5" y="0.5" width="52.87" height="84.29"/>
    <path d="M176.51,18.94v83.28H124.65V18.94h51.86m1-1H123.65v85.28h53.86V17.94Z" transform="translate(-123.65 -17.94)"/>
  </g>
  <g id="two" data-name="&lt;two&gt;" className="two">
    <rect x="0.5" y="101" width="52.87" height="49.87" style="fill: red"/>
    <path d="M176.51,119.43v48.88H124.65V119.43h51.86m1-1H123.65v50.88h53.86V118.43Z" transform="translate(-123.65 -17.94)" style="fill: red"/>
  </g>
  <g id="one" data-name="&lt;one&gt;" className="one">
    <rect x="0.5" y="171.82" width="52.87" height="87.53" style="fill: #8cc63f"/>
    <path d="M176.51,190.26v86.53H124.65V190.26h51.86m1-1H123.65v88.53h53.86V189.26Z" transform="translate(-123.65 -17.94)" style="fill: #8cc63f"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

and its base64 data is

```
"base64": "data:image/svg+xml;base64,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",
```

And thats what is in the image field in my database

I have tried everything I know of to change the fill of three boxes button onClick with no success.

This approach is clearly wrong:

```
              <button
                onClick={() => {
                  console.log("hello");

                  const colorch = () => {
                    const one = getElementById("one")
                    const two = getElementById("two")
                    const three = getElementById("three")
                    const randomColor = Math.floor(
                      Math.random() * 16777215
                    ).toString(16);
                    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#" + randomColor;
                    one.style.fill = "#" + randomColor;
                    two.style.fill = "#" + randomColor;
                    three.style.fill = "#" + randomColor;

                  };
                  colorch();
                }}
              >
                hello
              </button>
```

Any idea how to do this ?? Any help is truly appreciated

Comment: you'd have to edit the base64 data i.e. undecode it, edit it to change the fill colours then encode it again.

Comment: Is there a way to manipulate the svg image if I were to leave it as an svg file in the database ? Is putting it in a canvas a good idea ? I have even tried that but found myself lost and way over my head.